# Compare 2 dataframe with checking id a column value is in other dataframes column . If the value is there then change corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I have a situation , I have 2 Dataframes in python

```
df1 = {
    'A':['1','2','3'],
    'B':['c','d','e']
    },

df2 = {
    'X':['2','1'],
    'Y':['n','m']   
}
```

Now If A column matches any value in column X, I want B to have corresponding value of Y
in this case output:

```
df1 = {
    'A':['1','2','3'],
    'B':['m','n','e']
    }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series `created` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and replace missing values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['B'] = df1['A'].map(df2.set_index('X')['Y']).fillna(df1['B'])
print (df1)
   A  B
0  1  m
1  2  n
2  3  e
```